# How to configure webpack to find images in scss via this way: url(a.png) instead of url(../../image/a.png)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, sass

I am using typescript, webpack, sass in my project. now I set background-imgae in scss using this way: `url(../../assets/image/a.png)`,
however it is really ugly, I want to import image like this: `url(a.png)`, what should I do ?

I have used `url-loader`, file-loader, `resolve-url-loader` to solve the problem, actually, I am just a entry level of `webpack`. I am really confused now. Here is my code

**in wepack :**

```
{
        test: /\.scss|css$/i,
        use: [
          require.resolve("style-loader"),
          {
            loader: require.resolve("css-loader"),
            options: {
              importLoaders: 1
            }
          },
          {
            loader: require.resolve("sass-loader")
          },
          {
            loader: require.resolve("resolve-url-loader")
          },
          AntdScssThemePlugin.themify({
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: {
              sourceMap: true
            }
          }),
          {
            loader: require.resolve("postcss-loader"),
            options: {
              ident: "postcss",
              plugins: () => [
                require("postcss-flexbugs-fixes"),
                autoprefixer({
                  browsers: [
                    ">1%",
                    "last 4 versions",
                    "Firefox ESR",
                    "not ie < 9"
                  ],
                  flexbox: "no-2009"
                }),
                postcssAspectRatioMini({}),
                postcssPxToViewport({
                  viewportWidth: 375, // (Number) The width of the viewport.
                  viewportHeight: 1334, // (Number) The height of the viewport.
                  unitPrecision: 3, // (Number) The decimal numbers to allow the REM units to grow to.
                  viewportUnit: "vw", // (String) Expected units.
                  selectorBlackList: [".ignore", ".hairlines"], // (Array) The selectors to ignore and leave as px.
                  minPixelValue: 1, // (Number) Set the minimum pixel value to replace.
                  mediaQuery: false // (Boolean) Allow px to be converted in media queries.
                }),
                postcssWriteSvg({
                  utf8: false
                }),
                postcssCssnext({}),
                postcssViewportUnits({}),
                cssnano({
                  preset: "advanced",
                  autoprefixer: false,
                  "postcss-zindex": false
                })
              ]
            }
          }
        ]

      },
```

```
{
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        use: [
          "file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]",
          {
            loader: "image-webpack-loader",
            query: {
              mozjpeg: {
                progressive: true
              },
              gifsicle: {
                interlaced: false
              },
              optipng: {
                optimizationLevel: 4
              },
              pngquant: {
                quality: "75-90",
                speed: 3
              }
            }
          },
        ]
      },
```

In index.scss

```
 background: url("../../assets/images/sprite_languages.png")
```

and I really want to use this way:

```
background: url("sprite_languages.png")
```

What could I do? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in webpack config:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        '@assets': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/assets'),
    },
},
```

And then in scss:

```
 background: url("~@assets/images/sprite_languages.png");
```